# POP/IMAP collector for OS X Lion Server

Tags: email, osx-lion, imap, pop3, osx-server

Is there a way to have OS X Lion server pick up mails and distribute them among it's local users? 
I have a catch-all mailbox at the provider and am looking for a little program that could check every 5 minutes for new mails and then distribute them to its local users.

Due to the fact that the server is behind a dynamic IP, I want to grab all the mails centralized and distribute them locally.

I know such programs exist for MS Exchange-Server scenarios, but I can't seem to find any for OS X...

Maybe there is a unix command line tool that does it as well?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -2):

You may want to look at [Fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/).

Comment: Care to expand on that?